# About dev mapping of partitions

Tags: partition, device-mapper

New Linux user. Today had bright idea of making a backup of two partitions on an sd card to another sd card already in use. Did this: shrunk partition on backup sd, thus creating unallocated space, and copypasted the partitions to that space with gparted. I don't have two card reader drives on the laptop, so I used a usb-attachable sd-to-usb drive. All went well, except now debian can access and mount the partitions when ever I read the new card from the usb attached drive (they are mapped as /dev/sdbX) but when I put the card in the card reader slot, while it does see the partitions and show them as mmcblk0pX, it refuses to mount or read them. So, now I'm guessing that I had an oversimplified understanding of disk management in Linux, and would appreciate it some one could explain this and suggest a way to fix it. I though that the device mapping would be done automatically from the partition mapping, which seems not to be the case...

Comment: you're probably not so dumb after all. But might you elaborate a little on *refuses*? Maybe error messages? And probably a little `lsblk` output couldn't hurt... Very good question though. Also - `device-mapper` actually a factor here - like did you use `device-mapper` to layer the partitions somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, I thought device mapper was what created the /dev/* listings..

On refuses, I simply get a message: cannot mount device not found

Comment: probably not then.